# Pandas-create number of differences matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this

```
    L1  L2  L3  L4  L5
A   1   2   3   4   5
B   1   2   4   3   5
C   1   3   3   2   1
```

I want to calculate the number of differences between rows, for example the number of differences between A and B is 2, A and C is 3, B and C is 4.

What I really want is a difference matrix, such as

```
    A   B   C
A   0   2   3
B   2   0   4
C   3   4   0
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First loop solution is iterate by each row, compare by DataFrame and `sum`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: df.ne(x).sum(axis=1), axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C
A  0  2  3
B  2  0  4
C  3  4  0
```

Or for improve performance are compared values in numpy with broadcasting for 3d array, sum and last is used DataFrame constructor:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
out = pd.DataFrame((a != a[:, None]).sum(2), index=df.index, columns=df.index)
print (out)
   A  B  C
A  0  2  3
B  2  0  4
C  3  4  0
```

---

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randint(20, size=(100, 500)))
print (df)


In [119]: %%timeit
     ...: df.apply(lambda x: df.ne(x).sum(axis=1), axis=1)
     ...: 
     ...: 
12.8 s ± 1.02 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [120]: %%timeit
     ...: a = df.to_numpy()
     ...: pd.DataFrame((a != a[:, None]).sum(2), index=df.index, columns=df.index)
     ...: 
     ...: 
14.6 ms ± 325 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, jezrael. That's what I want